# Cambiar posición dígitos - Javascript

Tags: javascript

Necesito crear una función que contenga dos códigos y que estos se cambien de posición, por ejemplo el código 1234, que devuelva 2341,3412, 4123 y 1234 el codigo2 lo mismo con sus números. Como he hecho aquí:

```
function codeScript (code1, code2){
    for (var i = 0; i< code1.length; i++) {
        var firstNum1 = code1[1] + code1[2] + code1[3] + code1[0]
        var secondNum1 = code1[2] + code1[3] + code1[0] + code1[1]
        var thirdNum1 = code1[3] + code1[0] + code1[1] + code1[2]
        var result1= firstNum1 +"\n" + secondNum1 + "\n" + thirdNum1 + "\n" + code1
    }
    for (var i = 0; i< code2.length; i++) {
        var firstNum2 = code2[1] + code2[2] + code2[3] + code2[0]
        var secondNum2 = code2[2] + code2[3] + code2[0] + code2[1]
        var thirdNum2 = code2[3] + code2[0] + code2[1] + code2[2]
        var result2= firstNum2 +"\n" + secondNum2 + "\n" + thirdNum2 + "\n" + code2
    } 
    return result1 + "\n" + result2
}
```

Me gustaría que me ayudarais a sintetizar el código. Ya que luego tendría que multiplicar cada número de códigos por un número y que me devuelva códigos nuevos.

Comment: Puedes hablar de códigos *ofuscados*, pero eso no es cifrar, realmente

Comment: He cambiado título por cambiar posiciones. gracias

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lo que estás haciendo realmente es una operacion ROL (rotar a la izquierda / *rotate left*) tres veces, así que podrías crear una función que te resuelva esa funcionalidad y usarla las veces que necesites:

```js
function rotarTexto(t) {
 const aux = t.split(''); //creamos un array de caracteres
 aux.push(aux.shift()); //sacamos el primer elemento y lo metemos por el final
 return aux.join(''); //creamos de nuevo un string
}

let r = rotarTexto('12345');
console.log(r);
console.log(rotarTexto(r));
```

Answer (score 4):

Aunque la solución de @pablo-lozano funciona perfectamente me he puesto a experimentar con el destructuring de ES6 y he dado con una solución igual pero expresada de otra forma. La dejo aquí como mero ejercicio y por si a alguien le es útil:

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <script>
        function rol(arr){
            let [first, ...rest] = [arr.shift(), ...arr];
            return [...rest,...first];
        }

        let s = '1234';
        let aux = s.split('');
        for(let i=0;i<s.length;i++){
            aux = rol(aux);
            console.log(aux.join(''));
        }

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

La idea consiste es utilizar la [asignación por destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Destructuring_assignment) para obtener el primer valor del array (mediante `shift`). Guardaremos en la variable `first` el primer valor del `array` y en `rest` el resto del `array`. Ambas variables se unen con el [operador de propagación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Spread_operator) (`...`) en un único `array`. Para obtener todos los posibles valores utilizo un `for` hasta la longitud del `string` y voy actualizando la variable auxiliar con el `array`.